# Select the first occurence in a table in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a table A on hive that looks like this:

```
id   msts    action
123  1000    sleep
123  1010    eat
123  2001    sleep
456  1200    eat
456  1500    drink
```

What I want is to select for each `id` the whole set corresponding to `min(tmst)`. I could do that by running

```
select * 
from A t1 semi 
left join 
(select id, min(msts) as msts from A group by id)
 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.msts = t2.msts;
```

but I want to see if I can do it without a join (or a custom reducer) as it is time consuming.

EDIT: For clarification: what I am trying to get there is the first action each `id` does (the `action` corresponding to `min(msts)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's been some back in forth in the Hive community on whether to implement argmin and argmax udfs, which is exactly what you want here. The resolution was not to add it because there's a workaround with structs. The trick is that structs compare by the first field first, so you can convert your fields to a struct with the comparison field first, do the min, then un-struct the fields back out. In this case:

```
select s.id as id, s.msts as msts, s.action as action from (
  select min(named_struct('msts', msts, 'id', id, 'action', action)) as s
  from A group by id
) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to show the action field, you can't do it without joining.
If you don't need action field, try this:

```
    select id, min(msts) as msts
from A group by id;
```

Comment: That's the thing: I need the action field.